# Unexpected token import when importing from other ts file when running by mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, mocha.js, spectron

I have a Util class where I saved some info for my test classes

```
import * as electron from "electron";
import { Application } from "spectron";

export class TestUtils {
  public app: Application;
  public windowsCount = 2;

  public windowByIndex() { return this.windowsCount - 1; }

  public setUp() {
    // start application
    this.app = new Application({
      // path to electron app
      args: ["./dist/main.js"],
      path: "" + electron,
      startTimeout: 30000,
      waitTimeout: 30000,
    });
    return this.app.start();
  }

  public tearDown() {
    // close browser
    const windows = this.app.client.windowHandles() as any;
    this.app.client.close(windows.sessionId);
  }
}
```

and I have the following structure

[image]

what I am trying to do is to import the TestUtils with `import { TestUtils } from "../helpers/TestUtils"`

but then I got the error

```
import { TestUtils } from "../helpers/TestUtils"
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

my tsconfig.ts file contains

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I have changed the `app.e2e-spec.js` to `app.e2e-spec.ts` but I still got this error.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what is saying "unexpected token import" - TypeScript? Node.js? Your browser? A test runner? Something else?

Comment: You might also try setting "target" to "es5" under "compilerOptions" to see if that makes any difference for you.

Comment: es5 und es6 did not help . i got the error when running by mocha

Comment: When you run with Mocha, what version of Node.js are you using? Also, are you telling Mocha to run the .ts files directly? Or the compiled .js files? Because it's the compiled .js files that you really want to run (especially when "target" is "es5")